# What does "cloneNode" do here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this random code snippet that creates progress bar with async behaviour and I would like to know why cloneNode web api was used here. From mdn document, it basically clone the node and creates exact same node with attributes and id. But I would like to why `clonedProgress` which is cloneNode version of `progressBar` had to be used to create progress bar in this code. Why `progressBar` variable doesn't work? https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-browser-46gtcd?file=/src/index.js

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("button");
let progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress");
let promise = Promise.resolve();
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let clonedProgress = progressBar.cloneNode(true);
  clonedProgress.style.display = "block";

  promise = promise.then(
    () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        clonedProgress.querySelector(".bar").classList.add("loading");
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
        }, 2000);
      }, 0);
    })
  );
  document.body.appendChild(clonedProgress);
});
```

```css
.progress {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 2s ease-in 0s;
}

.loading {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<button id="addBtn">add+</button>
<div class="progress" style="display: none;">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It allows you to have multiple progress bars. Every time you click, it makes a copy of the progress bar and starts it moving.

Comment: It really should clean up though.

Comment: If you want to know what it does - the documentation has you covered. If you want to know *why* it's being used - there can be more than one progressBar per page, so you need a clone of the element for every progress bar instance. It's a templating mechanism.

Comment: Ok, since `document.querySelector(".progress")` can only be used once, in order to use multiple elements of that, use `cloneNode` to copy off element use them multiple times on the page. This clears things up.